# Java Synchronization Problems

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I am just starting to learn about Java concurrency and I am getting some strange output from the following code:

ThreadSafe.java:

```
public class ThreadSafe {
    private int value;

    public ThreadSafe() {
        value = 0;
    }

    public synchronized int getNext() {
        if (value >= 10000) {
            value = 0;
        }
        return value++;
    }
}
```

RunnableImpl.java:

```
public class RunnableImpl implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    private ThreadSafe ts;

    public RunnableImpl(String name, ThreadSafe ts) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ts = ts;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + ts.getNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadSafe ts = new ThreadSafe();

        Runnable a = new RunnableImpl("A", ts);
        Runnable b = new RunnableImpl("B", ts);

        new Thread(a).start();
        new Thread(b).start();
    }
}
```

Whenever the threads switch off, I get output like the following:

```
B: 7320
B: 7321
A: 4278 // What?
A: 7323
A: 7324
```

Going back up the output where `A` and `B` switch off:

```
A: 4275
A: 4276
A: 4277
B: 2279 // ROBBLE ROBBLE!
B: 4279
B: 4280
```

I can see that `A` left off at 4277 earlier on and picked up at 4278 before skipping 7322 and continuing on with 7323. This happens with both `value++` and `++value`. My understanding was that `synchronized` would let each thread's method invocation of `getNext()` complete before letting any other threads execute that method.

When I use `private volatile int value;` in `threadsafe.java` I get output similar to the following:

```
A: 8511
A: 8512
A: 8513
B: 7022 // Meh.
B: 8514
B: 8515
```

This time no numbers were skipped (from `++value`, still skips with `value++`) but the output still seems to be using a cached value for the first go.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Try to synchronize access to System.out aswell. Without it the output might be interrupted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ThreadSafe` class is fine. This is happening most probably because of the thread scheduling. Namely, in the first example, thread "A" got de-scheduled after fetching 4278 from the instance, but before printing it to the terminal.

Then "B" ran for a while, fetching all values up to 7322, and printing all values up to 7321 before being de-scheduled, at which point "A" was scheduled again, and its next step was to print the value it had previously fetched (4278), and the continuing with the next value from the `ThreadSafe` class (7323).

So your problem is that while fetching the numbers is properly thread-safe, printing them is not.

Comment: This makes sense :) Use a synchronized print method in the `ThreadSafe` class.

Comment: Chris: doing just that is not enough. For fetch + print to be properly atomic, both have to be executed in the same "synchronized" block. Having them be two separate methods means that you grab the lock, execute one method, drop the lock, grab it again, then execute the second. So there's still a window for a race.

Comment: What if I wanted to make the threads still do the printing (for whatever reason). What is the most straightforward way to make printing thread-safe? Off the top of my head I'm thinking of making a printer object with a static synchronized print method. Is there a less-round-about way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @KPThunder: easiest way is to put a `synchronized (ts) { }` block around your System.out.println call. That way your `getNext()` method doesn't need to be synchronized either. Or move the print call to the `getNext()` method (in which case it would turn into "get and print").

Comment: I understand the problem now.

Comment: Yay! It works now! But just a bit of nit-picking: if my getNext() method wasn't synchronized on its own then the class wouldn't be able to call itself `ThreadSafe`, now would it? More like `ThreadSafeForThreadsOfRunnableImpl`.

Comment: @KPthunder Well guess why lots of modern java collections aren't thread safe in themselves - it's more often than not quite useless, because just as in your example you need a higher level synchronization that the class itself can't offer.